# MySQL Joins Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to join 3 tables at the same time to get "School Name" from schools_informations table and "User ID, User Name, User Surname" from login table.

The thing i need to do is getting "User Data","School Data" and matching then by using the `user_id` and `school_id` in my `asc_to_school` table.

Here is my `schools_informations` table which i need to take the school_id and match it in the `asc_to_schools` table and `schools_name` to display as output ($variable):

```
 id | school_id | school_name     | school_type     | type | la_name         | region 
----+-----------+-----------------+-----------------+------+-----------------+--------
 1  | 8432627   | Glasgow Gaelic  | Local Authority | Both | Glasgow City    | WE
 2  | 5349834   | Breadalbane     | Local Authority | Both | Perth & Kinross | TF
 3  | 7235142   | ForestFortres   | Local Authority | Both | undefined       | WE
```

Here is my login table:

```
 id | username | pass | region | la               | name  | surname | role
----+----------+------+--------+------------------+-------+---------+------
 1  | Can      | **** |  none  | Clackmannanshire | Can   | Sinal   | ASC
 2  | Tumer    | **** |  none  | Argyll & Bute    | Tumer | Kologlu | GM
 3  | Kerem    | **** |  none  | Somethingelse    | Kerem | Citak   | ADM
 4  | Pelin    | **** |  none  | Somethingelse    | Pelin | Karahan | GM
 5  | Irem     | **** |  none  | Somethingelse    | Irem  | Sevinc  | CC
```

Lastly my `asc_to_school` table looks like that:

```
 user_id | school_id
---------+-----------
    1    | 1
    2    | 1
    3    | 2
    4    | 2
    5    | 3
```

Here is a query i tried:

```
SELECT 
u.id, u.name, u.surname, u.role, 
c.user_id, c.school_id, 
s.school_id,s.school_name 
FROM login u, asc_to_school c, school_informations s 
WHERE u.role = 'ASC' AND c.user_id = u.id AND c.school_id = s.id
```

As you can guess the SQL returned an empty result... I searched for this and found this example (the query i tried in an another question) but it didnt work for me.

How can I get: 
Only the users with the "role" = "ASC" 
and connect this user with the school by using the `asc_to_school` table.

***EDIT***

Here is the last query i have which works in SQL Fiddle:

```
SELECT 
u.id, u.name, u.surname, c.school_id, 
s.school_id,s.school_name 
FROM login u, asc_to_school c, school_informations s 
WHERE u.role = 'ASC' AND c.user_id = u.id AND c.school_id = s.id
```

And here is the result:

```
object(mysqli_result)#3 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(5)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(0)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

Comment: Your query looks fine (except that implicit joins are archaic, you should use explicit `JOIN` clauses). It returns a result for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e9c3c/1

Comment: Is this a school assignment?   You really should be learning to write queries in the much more standard ansi-92 format using joins...what you are writing here is very old and hard to read...still functions the same though.  Heh, your aliasing adds confusion too.  Otherwise...this looks right

Comment: @Twelfth To each his own, I strongly encourage aliasing. It allows you to have meaningful table names without creating overly verbose queries.

Comment: Let's break it down: Do you get a result if you do `SELECT * FROM login WHERE role = 'ASC'`?

Comment: How are you querying the database? If you are using phpmyadmin can you do a sql export of the 3 tables and paste them into your question? This way we will be certain of what data you actually have.

Comment: I too am very curious to see the data.

Comment: @Barmar - agreed, was simply suggesting to use alias's that make sense to the table name...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    u.id, 
    u.name, 
    u.surname, 
    u.role, 
    c.user_id, 
    s.school_id, 
    s.school_name 
FROM login u 
INNER JOIN asc_to_school c ON c.user_id = u.id 
INNER JOIN school_informations s ON s.id = c.school_id 
WHERE TRIM(u.role) = 'ASC'
```

Comment: Why did you use `LIKE` instead of `=`? That's an incompatible change to the logic.

Comment: Because he got an empty result set - there could be some extra characters or spaces in the role field. That is why I asked the OP to try it.

Comment: Better would be `WHERE TRIM(u.role) = 'ASC'`. Because `LIKE` will also match `ASC1`.

Comment: Still an empty result set... :'(

Comment: @EceKuru I suspect your real data may be different than what you have posted. As others have pointed out your query should have worked.

Comment: I think we should figure out why he's getting a different result from us before we go cargo-culting answers like this.

Comment: @EceKuru can you try with the TRIM as Barmar suggests? I have updated the sql above.

Comment: Check for case sensitivity in your table definitions and the actual data in the fields maybe? (if you have a case sensitive collation then 'ASC' <> 'Asc'. The query itself seems fine (if archaic)

Comment: I was adamant because TRIM is **more** restrictive than LIKE.

Comment: I suspect the data is somewhat different than what the OP has shown us here.

Comment: @EceKuru your original query should work - based on the data you have shown in your question. What do you get when you run this: SELECT * FROM login WHERE role = 'ASC'

Answer (score 0):

Use explicit JOIN syntax, that's much easier to understand and maintain:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.surname, u.role
     , c.user_id, c.school_id
     , s.school_name
FROM   login u
JOIN   asc_to_school       c ON c.user_id   = u.id 
JOIN   school_informations s ON s.school_id = c.school_id  -- ?not s.id?
WHERE  u.role = 'ASC';
```

I suspect you really want to join to `s.school_id`? Your example indicates otherwise, but I suspect the data in your ***example*** is misleading. Your text says:

> Here is my `schools_informations` table which i need to take the **`school_id`** and match it in the `asc_to_schools` table

Bold emphasis mine.
And <strike>`school_id`</strike> was duplicated in the `SELECT` list. Many client do not swallow duplicate column names.

Comment: You could be on to something with the duplicate school_id columns.